# Chess: Duplicate code in movement validations - Java

Tags: java, duplicates, chess

I am currently learning Java and working on a class assignment. We're supposed to make a "weird version" of Chess.
Like in original chess, pieces can't move if there is a piece in their way, the obvious exception being the Horse, which can hop over all pieces *except Kings*.

I have an abstract class `Piece` that is inherited by all the piece types, each with their own rules of movement. Most of them have this movement restriction, and so I have defined the methods in this class:

```
    public boolean freeWayHorizontally(int xO, int yO, int xD) {
    //RIGHT
    if (xO < xD) {
        for (int x = xO + 1; x < xD; x++) {
            CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.checkIfTheresPiece(x, yO);
            if (thereIsPiece != null){
                return false;
            }
        }
    //LEFT
    } else if (xO > xD) {
        for (int x = xO - 1; x > xD; x--) {
            CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.checkIfTheresPiece(x, yO);
            if (thereIsPiece != null){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean freeWayVertically(int xO, int yO, int yD) {
    //UP
    if (yO < yD) {
        for (int y = yO + 1; y < yD; y++) {
            CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.checkIfTheresPiece(xO, y);
            if (thereIsPiece != null){
                return false;
            }
        }
    //DOWN
    } else if (yO > yD) {
        for (int y = yO - 1; y > yD; y--) {
            CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.checkIfThereIsPiece(xO, y);
            if (thereIsPiece != null){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`thereIsPiece(int x, int y)` is a function from the Chess `Simulator` class that, given a position on the board, returns the piece in that position.

As is obvious, these two receive the same parameters (origin coordinates and a destination coordinate, where one of the destination coordinates is one of the piece's origin coordinates), so the only thing that really changes is the way `thereIsPiece()` is called. **EDIT:** And because of this, they're marked as duplicates, and from what I've been told, that's very bad!

However, I can't seem to figure out a way to solve this problem using only one of these methods; **ALSO AN EDIT:** I've tried overloading it, but then it'd work only vertically or horizontally (may have done it wrong).

The thing is I need these to be done separately to implement the Horse's movement, that overrides these methods:

```
public boolean freeWayHorizontally(int xO, int yO, int xD) { //Overriden by the Horse class
    //RIGHT
    if (xO < xD) {
        for (int x = xO + 1; x <= xD; x++) {
            CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.checkIfTheresPiece(x, yO);
            if (thereIsPiece != null && thereIsPiece.isKing){
                return false;
            }
        }
    //LEFT
    } else if (xO > xD) {
        for (int x = xO - 1; x >= xD; x--) {
            CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.checkIfTheresPiece(x, yO);
            if (thereIsPiece != null && thereIsPiece.isKing){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean freeWayVertically(int xO, int yO, int yD) { //Overriden by the Horse class
    //UP
    if (yO < yD) {
        for (int y = yO + 1; y <= yD; y++) {
            CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.checkIfTheresPiece(xO, y);
            if (thereIsPiece != null && thereIsPiece.isKing){
                return false;
            }
        }
    //DOWN
    } else if (yO > yD) {
        for (int y = yO - 1; y >= yD; y--) {
            CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.checkIfThereIsPiece(xO, y);
            if (thereIsPiece != null && thereIsPiece.isKing){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then calls its own type of movement check, also defined in the `Piece` class:

```
public boolean freeWayL(int xO, int yO, int xD, int yD) {
    boolean fH, fV;
    //Horizontal -> Vertical
    fH = this.freeWayHorizontally(xO, yO, xD);
    if (fH) {
        fV = this.freeWayVertically(xD, yO, yD);
        if (fV) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    //Vertical -> Horizontal
    fV = this.freeWayVertically(xO, yO, yD);
    if (dV) {
        fH = this.freeWayHorizontally(xO, yD, xD);
        if (fH) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What can I do to avoid all this duplication, or even to make these validations better?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question (probably just me).  What's happening at the moment?  Is it checking for a piece when you move a horse?  Welcome to stack overflow, btw

Comment: As stated, I have to check if there's a piece in the way of any piece's movement. Those two methods (freeWayHorizontally() and freeWayVertically()) check if there are any pieces blocking the piece to be moved in case it's moving up, down or to the sides. I call them for the Horse's movement type (an L), but because it can hop over other pieces (except Kings), I have to override those two methods in its class.
IntelliJ marks freeWayHorizontally() and freeWayVertically() as duplicates, and I also kind of have to duplicate them again in the Horse's class! I'd like to avoid that.
And thank you!

Comment: Why is L shaped movemen defined in the `Piece` class when only horses need it?

Comment: The project comes in "parts", so I don't know if more pieces will be added in the future. I've put it in the `Piece` class so I have a generic "there are pieces in the way" method for a L type of movement in case there's a new piece with a similar way of movement. Is this advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue with your code is that you have different method on `Simulador` class to check positions:

```
// When is checking horizontally
CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.pegaPecaPorCoordenada(x, yO);

// When is checking vertically
CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.checkIfThereIsPiece(xO, y);
```

I don't see a reason why this should not be a single method.

I can see 2 different point of improvement here:

1. rewrite the loop changing start and end in a way to have only one loop.

As an example:

```
public boolean freeWayHorizontally(int xO, int yO, int xD) {
    int destination = xD;
    int origin = xO + 1;
    if (xO > xD) {
        destination = xO - 1;
        origin = xD;
    }

    for (int x = origin; x < destination; x++) {
        CrazyPiece thereIsPiece = Simulador.pegaPecaPorCoordenada(x, yO);
        if (thereIsPiece != null){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

When you have the origin is before the destination, you move from origin to destination stight forward.

When the destination is before the origin, you just swap and move from destination to origin.

2. the second point is the check condition.

I think you should just add a method:

```
private boolean checkPositionIsFree(int x, int y) {
    return Simulador.pegaPecaPorCoordenada(x, y) != null;
}
```

Now you need to have one for the horizontal and one for the vertical, until you can't merge the 2 methods.

And then you can rewrite your method like so:

```
public boolean freeWayHorizontally(int xO, int yO, int xD) {
    int destination = xD;
    int origin = xO + 1;
    if (xO > xD) {
        destination = xO - 1;
        origin = xD;
    }

    for (int x = origin; x < destination; x++) {
        if (checkPositionIsFree(x, yO)){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

For the Horse, you just `@Override` the `checkPositionIsFree()` method with the proper condition (adding the check on the king), and everything should work.

**Update**

To cover completely the horse case you can have a method that work on the input data:

```
@Override
public boolean freeWayHorizontally(int xO, int yO, int xD) {
    return super.freeWayHorizontally(xO, yO, xD + 1);
}
```

In such a way you can avoid to rewrite all the code.

> By the way, your code here have some typos, maybe you rewrite it. It's better to check those kind of things, and have working code (in your case) or the exact code is failing, to avoid lost vouluntiers time following the wrong bug.

Comment: Whoops. I'm sorry, `checkIfTheresPiece` and `pegaPecaPorCoordenada` are actually the same method. I overlooked this when pasting the code for translation.
But the suggestion helps greatly! Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, that's good actually, as you can cut out more code. :)

Comment: This might sound rude, but I can see now that the problem is not entirely solved. 
The Horse needs to check xD and yD **inclusively** when performing the first `freeWayHorizontally` or `freeWayVertically`, but **exclusively** when it comes to its final destination (it's handled by a separate method). Ex: Horse at (2,2) wants to move to (4,4). It needs to check (2, 4) and (4, 2), and calling the methods like they are (`x < destination` instead of `x <= destination`) won't account for that.
Can I solve this without needing to override it?

Comment: Actually, you just need to change the x,y and destination you pass to the method in that case.

Comment: I had to fix a few things, but everything works fine now. Thank you!